# Macbook pro 2015 won’t turn on unless I disconnect and reconnect the battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

My problem is similar to this thread: [MacBook Air won't power on, except I remove the battery and plug it back in (SMC reset?) - sleep works](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231499/macbook-air-wont-power-on-except-i-remove-the-battery-and-plug-it-back-in-smc)

The Mac won’t turn on unless I unplug and replug the battery after holding down the power button for a few seconds. After that, I need to connect the charger and power on the Mac. This always happens if I shut it down.

My workaround as of the moment is just to make the Mac sleep but sometimes it would just drain the battery. It’s annoying. Has this problem been solved for others? I have tried every key combination and reset, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you are able to use the computer can you click the Apple logo>System Information>Power>then look for Cycle Count and Condition?

That should help determine if that battery needs replacing or it is the power management unit mentioned by @benwiggy

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware problem, which requires technical inspection of the device.

For a 7-year-old laptop, it's likely that the battery needs replacing. IT could alternatively be a problem with the power management unit (requiring a logic board replacement.)

Take it to an Apple Store, or another authorised Apple repair shop.